# Multiple web requests, start another request while waiting for response on last one. C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, httpwebrequest

I am trying to do multiple web requests from websites that take a long time to load  the full response (really long log files). I want to implement a method that will continue to create web requests while waiting for the response of the other ones and speed the process.

Tried to implement an async- await method but I don't think is creating simultaneous calls and  it's instead running synchronously. I am very confused in how to implement the async await, I looked at other similar questions but still not very clear, how could I fix this code to run async?
This is my code:

```
        public static async Task<String> MakeRequestAsync(String url)
    {
        String responseText = null;

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Proxy = null;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string sr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                response.Close();
                responseStream.Close();
                responseText = sr;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }
        return responseText;
    }
```

..

```
private void button_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)  //multiple requests
            {
                String a = AsyncTest().Result;
            }

    }

    private async Task<String> AsyncTest()
    {
        String b = await MakeRequestAsync(url);
        return b;
    }
```

Also any suggestions on how could I speed this process would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Range(0, 5)
    from r in Observable.Using(
        () => new WebClient(),
        wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString($"{url}{n}")))
    select new { n, r };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ToArray()
        .Select(xs => xs.OrderBy(x => x.n).Select(x => x.r).ToArray())
        .Subscribe(rs =>
        {
            /* Do something with the results */
        });
```

It's all multi-threaded and non-blocking.

If you don't care about the order in which the results are returned then just do this:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Range(0, 5)
    from r in Observable.Using(
        () => new WebClient(),
        wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString($"{url}{n}")))
    select r;

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(r =>
        {
            /* Do something with each result */
        });
```

Calling `subscription.Dispose()` will stop the query if you need to cancel it.

---

You can write your `MakeRequestAsync` method like this:

```
public static async Task<String> MakeRequestAsync(String url)
{
    return await
        Observable.Using(
            () => new WebClient(),
            wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString(url)));
}
```

Comment: Will this solution use 5 threads that block while it downloads the string?

Comment: It works like a charm, although if I try to return the string r from this method I get an error: "Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value" . what type of return can I do from this method in order to access the string?

Comment: @BLM `WebClient.DownloadString` is a blocking operation. That means you need to spin up background threads, that just hang around and wait for the result to come. This means you are robbing your threadpool of worker threads for no reason.

Comment: @JohanP - `WebClient.DownloadString` is a blocking operation if called on the current thread, but Rx pushes to a background thread. You have full control of what scheduling is used.

Comment: @BLM - I've added code for your `MakeRequestAsync` method.

Comment: @Enigmativity The issue isn't the type of scheduling used, the problem is _some_ thread is going to have to block and wait for and IO operation, whereas _some_ thread should ideally make the call, return immediately to the pool and when the IO completes, run the continuation. It's the equivalent of watching the kettle boil whereas you could be washing the dishes while it happens.

Comment: @JohanP - Does `Observable.Using(() => new WebClient(), wc => Observable.FromAsync(() => wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)))` solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

None of your IO calls are `async`.  `WebRequest` has no `async/await` pattern either, you can get `async` behaviour using `BeginGetResponse` with `AsyncCallback` but there is a better way to go. Use `HttpClient` rather, it is the recommend way to make http calls.

I.e

```
public static async Task<String> MakeRequestAsync(string url)
{

    using(var client = new HttpClient()) // don't do this, inject it as a singleton
    {
       using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url)
          return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }  
}
```

and then change your `Click` handler to be an `async void`:

```
private async void button_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
     for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)  //multiple requests
     {
        tasks.Add(MakeRequestAsync(url));
     }
     await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // wait for all of them to complete;
     foreach(var task in tasks)
     {
         var str = await task; // or task.Result, won't block, already completed;
     }
}
```

Comment: _"  WebRequest has no async/await pattern either"_ - wow really? +1

Comment: this is working, it waits on the response of the first call while making other requests on the meantime, but after a while the first call is never finished (slow request) and throws a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'A task was canceled.' exception, is this some sort of timeout from the request?

Comment: @BLM sounds like a new question?

Comment: @BLM yes, it is a timeout issue. You need to set `Timeout` property on the http client

Comment: follow up question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231995/infinite-timeout-web-request-c-sharp